# If you dont include an image does it use bandwidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, static

If I was making a static website and it had a folder called images which stored all the images. Assume I only included 2/10 of the images in that folder on the website in my html. If someone views the website are all the images downloaded or just them 2?

If it is only the 2 images use bandwidth, what happens if I use jquery to change the src of one of the images, is another image downloaded from the server?

Comment: You could easilly test this by looking a the "network" tab of the dev tools. As soon as you'll change an `img` src, it will be downloaded if not already in the browser cache.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this user is enough of newbie that he doesn't know what that is.

Comment: Browser's do not know what is in a server's directories, so it wouldn't know the resource locations (urls) of other images that were not included / loaded in the page and thus are not able to download them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the images that are called will take up bandwidth. If you had 1000 images in your folder and only displayed 2, then it would only consume the bandwidth of 2 images plus the HTML, etc.